# Assigning XY positions to points based on a "weight" between them

Tags: math, graph, cluster-analysis

I have a bunch of points in a graph, and for every pair of these points I have "weight" value indicating what their proximity should be, between -1 and 1.

I want to choose XY coordinates for these points such that those that have a proximity of 1 are in the same position, and those with a proximity of -1 are distant from each-other.  All points must reside within a bounded area.

What algorithms should I investigate to achieve this?

Comment: Are the weight values an exact measure for the proximity, or just an approximation? If they are an exact measure, the problem is easier, but there may be more impossible configurations

Comment: When you say "for every pair", does it mean that if you have 4 points you have 6 weights (one weight for each pair)?

Comment: I must be missing something, because it seems to me that you just need to replace each pair of vertices with proximity 1 with a single vertex whose edges are the edges of the original 2 vertices.

Comment: The weights are just an approximation, and yes, I can determine a weight between any given pair (its actually a pearson correlation coefficient).

Comment: This question is rather vague. Can you provide an example. Suppose you have points A, B, C, and D with weights of 1, 1, 0.5 and -0.5 respectively. Your bounded region is a square with coords of (-2, -2) and (2, 2). What would expect the coordinates of the 4 points to be. If we add another point, C' with a weight of 0.5, will it have the same coordinates of C, or will it be someplace else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for a [spring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law) equation.